# Helmで改行付きのValueを埋め込む方法

Tags: kubernetes

KubernetesのHelmで、ConfigMapに改行を含む値をvalues.yamlから取り込もうとしています。

**values.yaml**

```
configFile:
  hoge.txt: |
    aaa=bbb
    ccc=ddd
  fuga.txt: |
    aaa=bbb
    ccc=ddd
```

**template/configmap.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
data:
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.configFile }}
  {{ $key }}: |
    {{ $value }}
{{- end }}
```

このとき、上記のようにaaa=bbb + 改行 + ccc=dddのケースでは、Helmでエラーとなります。

```
YAML parse error on xxx/templates/configmap.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line n: could not find expected ':'
```

一方、値がaaa=bbbのみで改行がないケースでは期待通り動いています。

改行を含む値をHelmで正しく埋め込む方法についてご教授頂ければ幸いです。